# Beamer: \tableofcontents does not skip me to the right content

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I am trying to click the sections in the `Agenda` frame which should skip me to the particular frame related to the section. For example if I click the `related Projects` in the Agenda frame I want to skip directly to the  slide with the following content `Start the Related Projects slide.` but I am always get to the `Introduction` slide with this content `Start the introduction slide.` regardless what I click. How can I get it to work?

**tex code**

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\title{Test}
\author{Alex XYZ}
\institute{University XYZ}
\date{20.01.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Agenda}
\tableofcontents
\section{Introduction}
\section{ Requirements}
\section{Related Projects}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
Start the introduction slide. 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Requirements}
Start the Requirements slide.
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Related Projects}
Start the Related Projects slide.
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToC` links can only jump to different frames/section if the relevant target`\section` contains at least a different frames. But all the sections where in the same frame in the O.P's example, so the targets where all on the same frame, i.e. the `ToC` frame in this case.

Solution: Move the `\section` calls to the relevant frames.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\title{Test}
\author{Alex XYZ}
\institute{University XYZ}
\date{20.01.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Agenda}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
Start the introduction slide. 
\end{frame}

\section{Requirements}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Requirements}
Start the Requirements slide.
\end{frame}

\section{Related Projects}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Related Projects}
Start the Related Projects slide.
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: but with your solution if I click the sections in the `Agenda` frame I do not jump to another frame. Also nothing happens if I click a section and I always stay at the `Agenda` frame.

Comment: @TheBook: Have you compiled twice? I can click the section names and get to the right sections then